# Как реализовать обработчик события открытия вкладки Bootstrap pills

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Есть вкладки стандартной Bootstrap структуры:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id='mehan-termoregul'  class="tab-pane in active">
    <? echo do_shortcode('[catablog_gallery id="40" navigation="disable" template="tovar"]'); ?>
  </div>  
  <div id='cifr-termoregul'  class="tab-pane fade">
    <? echo do_shortcode('[catablog_gallery id="41" navigation="disable" template="tovar"]'); ?>
  </div> 
</div>
```

PHP код подтянет несколько divов. Стоит задача по открытию очередной вкладки к этим дивам применить определенный js. Вычитал что для этого используют обработчик:
  `$(‘a[data-toggle=»tab»]’).on(‘shown’,function(e){
e.target // активная вкладка
e.relatedTarget // предыдущая вкладка
})`    но не знаю как это грамотно применить. У дивов будет класс .catablog-item. Подскажите, будьте добры, как к ним применить js по открытию вкладки в которой они находятся. Благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел работающее решение:

`

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

  var target = $(e.target).attr("href"); 
 
  // ваш код

}
```

`
Переменной target присваивается открытая вкладка и дальше с ней можно делать то что необходимо.